# How to ignore if a cell is empty nothing

Tags: vb.net

How to use roscolor() but to ignore value (like empty cell) ?
I color row if value is upper than 5 but when there is nothing in the cell, i want to ignore the roscolor() apply, how?

```
Public Sub RosColor()
    For i As Integer = 0 To QuoteDataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        Dim val As Integer
        val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        If val = vbEmpty Then

            QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White

        ElseIf val < 5 Then
            QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf val > 5 And val < 10 Then
            QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow


        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Public Sub RosColor()
        For i As Integer = 0 To QuoteDataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
            Dim val As Integer
            val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            If val = vbEmpty Then

                QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White

            ElseIf val < 5 Then
                QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
  
            End If

        Next
    End Sub

Comment: Please put applicable code in the post not as a comment so it can be formatted and read

Comment: If you use one of the Paint or Format events, you dont have to loop thru the rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the empty value as following

```
Public Sub RosColor()
    For i As Integer = 0 To QuoteDataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        Dim val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        If IsDBNull(val) or val Is Nothing Then
            QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        ElseIf CInt(val) < 5 Then
            QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf CInt(val) > 5 And CInt(val) < 10 Then
            QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
        End If
```

Comment: Excellent ; must i keep val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value as well?

Comment: If i use val is nothing : doesn't work
if i use IsDBNull error debug and val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value is show slected in my code source

Comment: I did Mehang, i used:  val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            If IsDBNull(val) Then
                QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White

Comment: So it worked??? If so then you can take it as correct answer and upvote it or feel free to ask.

Comment: Everything seems to work well until i selecte the new row to create new entry, debug get in action and stop the application

Comment: What is the issue saying??

Comment: SystemInvalidCastException: DBNull in type 'Integer' is not valid

Comment: I tried edited code val Is nothing Then (doesn't work) and IsDBNull(val) works but wheni select new line (blank) to edit the row, i have SystemInvalidCastException

Comment: it is due to that line: val = QuoteDataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value